# mongo shell ReferenceError: database_name not found

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongodb-compass

Hello I've been using mongodb with mongo shell and I keep having the same problem.
While the database called Videos exists in MongoDB Compass and I can use it and add data to it, when I try to access it from the mongosh with this command:

```
Videos.getCollectionNames();
```

or with this command:

```
Videos.GBvideos.find();
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: Videos is not defined
```

This happens both with the integrated mongosh (inside the Compass env.) and with the mongosh executable from the installation path.

Any ideas how to get over this error?

I need to use the shell as what I want to do can't be done with the Compass

Compass:
[image: This is what I see from Compass]

Comment: if you execute "show dbs"  , "use Videos;db.GBvideos.find();" ?

Comment: show dbs returns

`Videos  88.2 MB
admin     41 kB
config   127 kB
local   73.7 kB`


use Videos;db.GBvideos.find();
returns:

`MongoshInvalidInputError: [COMMON-10001] Invalid database name: Videos;db.GBvideos.find()`

Comment: mongos> use Videos
switched to db Videos
mongos> db.GBvideos.find();
mongos>

Comment: `use Videos switched to db Videos` worked for me thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way in single command:

```
   mongos> db.getSiblingDB("Videos").getCollection("GBVideos").find()
   { "_id" : ObjectId("61eef2439f3fb15d1fef8877"), "test" : 1 }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("61eef24e9f3fb15d1fef8878"), "test" : 1 }
   mongos>
```

Or if you need your way you must assingn to variable:

```
   mongos> var Videos=db.getSiblingDB("Videos")
   mongos> Videos.GBVideos.find()
   { "_id" : ObjectId("61eef2439f3fb15d1fef8877"), "test" : 1 }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("61eef24e9f3fb15d1fef8878"), "test" : 1 }
   mongos>
```

Answer (score 1):

`use Videos switched to db Videos`
is the way to change the database from the mongo shell kudos to R2D2!!